# How To Store Meshes in Game [Not in Editor mode]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried Assetdatabase and then I came to know that it works only in editor mode ... How can I store the Mesh now in playing mode and then I want to load it also??

```
var savePath1 = "Assets/" + saveMaterial + ".asset";
if (AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(savePath1, typeof(Mesh))) {
    AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset(savePath1);
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(pf.mesh, savePath1);
    //here pf is a reference of sphere(gameobject)   
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of what you tried so far

Comment: thanks @derHugo I know how to use Assetdatabse ... I don't know any method that already exists to store the mesh in playing mode ... I am little bit updating my problem . it actually means that it will throw an error when i will build it using Assetdatabase.Create() in c# script

Comment: So, I need a method or a way to store the mesh so that I can store and Load the mesh even after the building the game ... [I Hope you have understood the issue now ]

Comment: Also, I have searched many questions regarding this .. One I got was if i will use Unity Resource.Load() this will help in Loading the data .. but I still don't Know how to store.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your question is currently to broad. I can't see how you currently get and store your mesh. There are [a lot of file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats#3D_graphics) that can be used for storing and loading meshes on runtime (STL, OBJ, FBX, COLLADA etc). e.g. [UnityFBXExporter](https://github.com/KellanHiggins/UnityFBXExporter) or [Scene OBJ exporter](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/scene-obj-exporter-22250/reviews)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html .... this one for loading

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html .. this one for storing.

Comment: I know which methods exist but please add your code ... I don't know what types of file / parameters you pass in there and how exactly you **use** it.

Comment: @derHugo added and  thanks too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Mesh is a relatively simple structure, for a single submesh you can serialize quite easily to json or other format in runtime

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MeshEquivalent
{
    public Vector3[] vertices;
    public Vector3[] normals;
    public Vector2[] uv;
    public int[] triangles;
    public MeshEquivalent(Mesh mesh)
    {
        vertices = mesh.vertices;
        uv = mesh.uv;
        normals = mesh.normals;
        triangles = mesh.triangles;
    }
}
```

There's also other uv channels (which you might not need), submeshes (same) and bounds which you can recalculate. The opposite process can be used to rebuild that mesh.